# Не понятно почему в коде автора есть одна строка. Код работает и без нее

Tags: flask

```
@auth.route('/change-password', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def change_password():
    form = ChangePasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if current_user.verify_password(form.old_password.data):
            current_user.password = form.password.data
            db.session.add(current_user)
            flash('Your password has been updated.')
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('auth/change_password.html', form = form)
```

Когда самостоятельно реализовал функцию, пошел сравнивать с функцией написанной автором и там у него эта строчка db.session.add(current_user). Функция работает и без нее. Зачем добавлять current_user в базу данных?

Comment: Что такое `db`? Что это за база данных такая и откуда эта переменная берётся?

Comment: db это база данных, где хранятся данные пользователей. current_user импортируется из расширения flask-login.

Comment: Ничего конкретного не ответили. Впрочем, я уже сам догадался, что это SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

Тут не добавляется юзер, а просто изменяется значение поля с паролем, насколько я понимаю из кода. Затем измененная запись пишется в БД

Comment: значение поля с паролем изменяется без этой строки.

Comment: @АлиКартоев судя по документации SQLAlchemy, этот `add` всё-таки нужен. Если всё работает и без него, то предположу, что `add` вызывается неявно в каком-нибудь другом месте проекта (например, в миддлварьке какой-нибудь, записывающей к примеру время последнего посещения, или что-нибудь ещё такое)

Comment: Вы правы, оказывается в самой модели User вызывается add. Получается автор просто забыл про это.